# Can Azure Devops send mail when a task fails while parallel stages are still running

Tags: azure-devops

As in, I have a pretty wide YAML multi-stage pipeline. There are instances where a parallel task can fail, but it will still be hours before the build fails and we get notified. One task might not negate the whole build, and could be retried in time to finish with the other stages if it was known.

Also, we don't want this on every pipeline in the project, just the important ones.

If so, how? Subscription sends on build fail.

Comment: yes, it can ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a powershell task to cancel current build if the task(let's say Task A) would fail. So that the build will be cannceled and you will be notified in time when Task A fails

First add a powershell task right after Task A, use [condtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) set this powershell task to be executed only when Task A failed.

In the powershell task call [build update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to cancel the current build if Task A failed. For below powershell task example.

> In order your pipeline to have the permission to cancel the current running build. You need go to your pipeline, click on the **3dots** and choose **Manage security**

[image]

> Then set the **Stop builds** permission to Allow for user **Project Collection Build Service(projectName)**,

[image]

In below powershell task, the script first get the current build using **get build by buildid api**. And then set the  `$build.status = "cancelling"`. Then update current build using build update api.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      condition: failed()
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          $header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)" }
          $buildsUrl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"
          $build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -Header $header

          $build.status = "cancelling"
          $body = $build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
          $urlToCancel = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"
          Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlToCancel -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Header $header
```